# open DataReader associated with this Command

Tags: ssms, datareader, bacpac

I'm using *Database > Import Data-tier Application* to pull in my .BACPAC file and am getting this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. (System.Data)

I am trying this from a fresh reboot of the machine so there are no other previous connections. How do I close the DataReader / fix the problem?

I've tried posting this on the Database Administrators but no-one seemed to know how...

Answer (score 6):

I think this may be a bug in SSMS.

I worked around it by pasting this in "Additional Connection Parameters".

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Comment: If someone is wondering where to provide "Additional Connection Parameters" value then disconnect your sql instance in ssms and connect again, in connect to server dialog, click on options buttion and in last tab "Additional Connection Parameters" can be found. Here you can provide MultipleActiveResultSets=True; and click connect button. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in SSMS version 18.6 Preview
Updating to the recently released v18.6 Stable Release solved the problem.